# how can I solve the stack overflow in 2D code?

Tags: c++

I produce a code that simulate dam break flow. I use many normal arrays. when I run the code it is ok and ave result but when I increase the number of cells 100x100 it show stack overflow and the run stop immediately. how can I solve the problem without using dynamic arrays?

Comment: Please show the code you're using that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I solve the problem without using dynamic arrays?

[Increase the stack size available for your process](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5DIncrease+the+stack+size).

Comment: @BasheerAl_Hadeethi Lookup the search results I've linked.